# Git : How to disable the --no-verify option while doing a git commit?

Tags: git, githooks

I have some code quality checks in the git's pre-commit hook, which the developers can easily bypass using `git commit -m "My commit message" --no-verify`.

I would like to disable the `--no-verify` option. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: They can also bypass them by cloning the repo and committing in the clone, then pushing.  I think if you want code-quality checks which can't be bypassed you need to be implementing them using some CI tool based off the origin repo.

Comment: You can't. My repository is *mine*, my fingers are mine, and my computer is mine. I can type whatever I want into my computer, and my Git runs my commands on my computer. You can, of course, *tell* your employees not to do that, and discipline or even fire them if they do, but that's not the way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you cannot forbid anything that the developers do on their machines. You should setup a CI server to verify commits as they are pushed to the repository. Commits are rather for developers and you shouldn't impose any restrictions on creating them.